# how to introduce section content in a thesis

Tags: past-tense

In my thesis work I want to explain the content of a section,
my question is which is the best form to introduce the section, for example:

In this section are described the technologies ...

or

In this section have been described the technologies ...

thanks in advance

Dom

Comment: Your 2 examples have a grammatical error as the technologies... are the ones being described, not the section.

Comment: @Rathony: Neither of them is a grammatical error. It's just inversion with the passive voice, which is perfectly grammatical although somewhat formal.

Comment: @PeterShor I understand your valid point. However, I don't necessarily agree to placing "are/have been" before described as it is not absolutely/grammatically necessary. The below Ricky's answer is the better inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Described in this section are the technologies that ..."
"Described in the following section are the technologies that ..."